# Please help to solve syntax error in iteration

Tags: python, input, integer

I want to make a code that if users put 100 and the number decrease by 10. 100 90 80....0

However, I faced this problem...

```
space = int(input("Enter the number : ")) # i will enter 100 here
for i in range(space, 0, -10) :  
    print(i)
```

> SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: What is 'repitation'?

Comment: Sorry. iteration. like for, while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
space = int(input("enter input: ")) # cook your dish here
for n in range(space, 0, -10):
    print(n)
```

The above code worked just fine in online ide(in Pyth 3.6), I don't see any problem in identifier. May be check your indentation, or your env (running code in compiler of different language) but even that should not give such an error.

Comment: I tried in google colab and it works now! Thank you for checking my code:)